# How to count the results of a specific survey?

Tags: mysql

I created a survey/polling application and after a user answers a given question I want to display the total responses for the question they answered.

I am trying to aggregate the responses of a specific quetsion with `COUNT` (I will have the `question_id` stored in the session variable of Flask).

[image]

[database schema and instance data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ID19.jpg)

I want to combine the output of these two queries into a single query, where the count of the result is paired up with the corresponding choice text:

```
-- Displays text of choices
SELECT choice.text
FROM choice
WHERE question_id = 12;

-- Displays how many times the question was answered with a choice
SELECT count(*) 
FROM answer 
WHERE question_id = 12 
GROUP BY choice_id;
```

These are all of my failed attempts. I will change 12 to a dynamic variable in the application, this was just for testing.

```
SELECT COUNT(a.choice_id), c.text  
FROM answer AS a, question AS q, choice AS C 
WHERE a.question_id = q.question_id 
GROUP BY c.choice_id;

SELECT COUNT(a.choice_id)
FROM answer AS a, question AS q 
WHERE a.question_id = 12
GROUP BY a.choice_id;

SELECT COUNT(a.choice_id), c.text
FROM answer AS a, question AS q, choice AS c
WHERE a.question_id = q.question_id AND a.question_id = c.question_id
GROUP BY a.choice_id;

SELECT *
FROM choice AS c 
WHERE c.question_id in (
  SELECT COUNT(a.choice_id)
  FROM answer AS a, question AS q 
  WHERE a.question_id = 12 --VARIABLE DATA FOR QUESTION
  GROUP BY a.choice_id
);

SELECT DISTINCT(q.text)
FROM answer AS a, question AS q
WHERE a.question_id = 12;

SELECT COUNT(c.choice), c.text,
FROM choice AS c, answer AS a
WHERE c.question_id = 12
GROUP BY c.choice;

SELECT COUNT(choice.choice_id)
FROM choice, answer
WHERE answer.question_id = 12
GROUP BY choice.choice;
```

Comment: Can you share the table structure, sample input data, and the expected output?

Comment: Also, what does "the total responses for the question they answered" mean? How many people already answered that given question?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have updated the question to perhaps make things more clear... I have two queries that achieve what I want, I do not know how to combine them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is that( total number of times the question is answered based on each option), for example

Q1 is answered 2 times with choice 1.
Q1 is answered 5 times with choice 4.
Q1 is answered 4 times with choice 2.
Q1 is answered 3 times with choice 3.

**Well, here is the answer**

```
   SELECT 
   NAME AS question_name,
   cname AS choice_name,
   COUNT(id) AS total_count
   FROM
    answer AS a,
    question AS q,
    choice AS c
   WHERE
   a.qid = q.id and a.cid=c.cid and a.qid = 1
   GROUP BY
     a.cid
```

**Sceenshot**

[image]

Comment: When applying it exactly to my schema: `SELECT q.text as Question, c.text AS Chocie, COUNT(c.choice_id) AS Responses
FROM question AS q, choice AS c, answer as a
WHERE a.question_id = q.question_id and a.choice_id = c.choice_id and q.question_id = 12
GROUP BY a.choice_id;`